# Regex Matching Phone Number

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex which will match anything which looks like a phone number. If there's more than one number in a string, match both of them. A phone number is defined as:

- 10+ characters
- Does not end in `N`, but can end in other letters/words

So I'd like to match these:

- 07158245215
- 01244356356
- 07158245215Y
- 01244356356Y
- 07158245215P
- 01244356356P
- 07158245215X
- 01244356356X
- 07158245215 work
- 01244 356356 work
- work 07158 245215 / home 07158 245215    // might be a difficult one
- work 01244356356

And disallow these:

- 071582  45215N
- 01244356356N
- 01244356356 N

I've toyed with negative lookahead/lookbehind but I can't get anything intelligible out. Is tis even possible or shall I do it in a higher language like .NET?

Comment: Do you mean "match an entire string that contains at least one phone number" or "extract phone number(s) from a longer string"?

Comment: Ideally it would extract numbers from a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?:\d\s*){10,}(?![\d\s]*N)
```

will match a 10+ digit phone number within a longer string, as long as that number is not followed by `N`. It allows any number of spaces between each digit.

If all your phone numbers always start with `0` as in your example, you can explicitly code that into the regex:

```
\b0\s*(?:\d\s*){9,}(?![\d\s]*N)
```

[See it on RegExr](http://regexr.com?32qic).